# Integrating Firebase App [FIRApp configure] makes window, navigationController nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm supposed to migrate from Digits to Firebase. While migrating I've got struck while implementation.

Followed [Firebaseguide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/start)

Got samples from :
https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    [FIRApp configure]; // This is causing the window and navigationController nil.

    self.window                    = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.navigationController      = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[[SplashScreen alloc] init]];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTranslucent:NO];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    if(userLoggedIn()) {
           self.root = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
           self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.root];
           self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
    }
}
```

Here I'm using rootViewController is UIViewController where I'm having a left menu.

If `[FIRApp configure]`the app is not stable. Not stable in the sense after view controller is shown,

`(((AppDelegate *)UIApplication.sharedApplication.delegate).window)`

the value is nil. If I'm not using [FIRApp configure]; then value is expected one.

Can anyone provide the right path to the solution. Since it is of FirebaseCore.framework I'm unable to proceed further.

Can anyone please provide your suggestion on this. Also I'm getting the following error while verifying phone number.

```
Error Domain=FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17054 "If app delegate swizzling is disabled, remote notifications received by UIApplicationDelegate need to be forwarded to FIRAuth's canHandleNotificaton: method." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=If app delegate swizzling is disabled, remote notifications received by UIApplicationDelegate need to be forwarded to FIRAuth's canHandleNotificaton: method., error_name=ERROR_NOTIFICATION_NOT_FORWARDED}
```

Comment: Did added Firebase Plist file

Comment: Yes. Added the plist file.

Comment: Are there any messages in the log? Calling configure shouldn't effect the state of the window at all. Since you mentioned as well, the source of FIRApp is here: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/master/Firebase/Core/FIRApp.m#L83

Comment: Calling configure affects the window. Because when I comment this single line the problem disappears. In documents they were told about swizzling app delegate methods. I think there seems problem. I'm looking on the issue.

Comment: I've seen some other problems around where the solution was to override AppDelegate's init method and move the configure call into the init method. Maybe worth a try.